# How to split a numpy array into subarrays based on a list of numbers?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `numpy.array` that holds some time-series data, where `data[:,0]` is the time, and the other columns are some measurements. I also have a `list_of_peaks` which is a list of times where there is something interesting in the data.

My goal is to calculate a certain measure for each point in `list_of_peaks` which is based the points in `data` closer to it than any other peak, i.e. I want to partition `data` halfway between each point in `list_of_peaks`.

My current (very slow) algorithm is this:

```
def measure(d,t_m,t_p):
    radius = d[(d[:,0] > t_m)* (d[:,0] < t_p)]
    return np.max(radius) - np.min(radius)

list_of_measures = []
for i in range(len(list_of_peaks)):
    if i == 0:
        list_of_measures.append(measure(data,data[0,0],(list_of_peaks[i+1] - list_of_peaks[i])/2+list_of_peaks[i]))
    elif i == len(list_of_peaks) - 1:
        list_of_measures.append(measure(data,list_of_peaks[i] - (list_of_peaks[i]-list_of_peaks[i-1])/2,data[-1,0]))
    else:
        list_of_measures.append(measure(data,list_of_peaks[i] - (list_of_peaks[i]-list_of_peaks[i-1])/2,(list_of_peaks[i+1] - list_of_peaks[i])/2+list_of_peaks[i]))
```

I haven't found any nice built-in `numpy` function that would serve my purpose, but I am pretty sure this can be done a LOT better, I just don't think see how.

Comment: [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) does literally just that

Comment: I read `np.split` at least twice and all the other splits and every time it seems I skimmed to the part where it says split into N equal parts ...

Comment: The equal part is only for when you enter an integer, you can specify indices like this: `np.split(data, list_of_peaks)`, assuming `list_of_peaks` contains indices like [5,7,10....]. Just look at the 2nd [example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.split.html)

Comment: @Brenlla Hmm, so it's not exactly what I need, since I don't have the indices, since `list_of_peaks` has times (i.e. values) not indices. I now have a oneliner that gives me the values where I need to split, I just have to figure out how to get the indices quickly from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brenlla pointed out, `np.split` can do most of what I want, so it came down to find the indices the fastest. Fortunately, there is also a built-in `numpy` function that is very fast for a time-series, since it is a sorted list by definition. The final map may have a faster solution, but the slow part of this algorithm was the splitting anyway:

```
splitter = np.ediff1d(list_of_peaks)/2 + list_of_peaks[:-1]
splitter_ind = np.searchsorted(data[:,0],splitter,side='right')
split_data = np.split(data[:,1],splitter_ind)
measures = np.array(list(map(lambda x: np.max(x) - np.min(x),split_data)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy.where() ( np.where())

```
x = np.array([
    [0.1, 0.4, 0.7],
    [0.3, 0.5, 0.2],
    [0.9, 0.1, 0.8],
])
y = x[np.where(x[:,1] == 0.5)]
y
[[0.3 0.5 0.2]]

# or with multiple condition

y = x[np.where((x[:, 1] > 0.1 ) & (x[:, 1] < 0.5))]
y
[[0.1 0.4 0.7]]
```

Comment: I think this would require looping through all the values and calling `np.where` separately for them.